# Setting up an opt-in system-wide vim config

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-vundle

I'm working on a Python 3.6 project (with **several friends** that are **new to Unix**) using vim on a debian-based system I own. I'm wondering if there's a way I can setup a **system-wide vim configuration using Vundle** so that we can all be on the same page and have the same tools available.

I know that I can create `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` in conjunction with installing plugins outside of my home directory and it will be sourced for all users, but for the future **I'm curious of the ways I can make using this global configuration an "opt-in" process,** so that a user could choose whether to use the global vim setup or make their own.

I can think of a few ways to do this, but I wanted some input from others before I tunnel into one of my approaches. Ideally this would require as little as possible from the user-end, since most of the others are extremely new to Unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it opt-in, do not use a config file that is searched for by Vim.

The user should create a `.vimrc` containing a single line:

```
source /path_to_your_custom.vim
```